# WPF page content not setting to window's size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I made a WPF application in which. I placed a rectangle. The page is covering whole window but the size(width) of rectangle is not equal to the page.

here is the pic.

here is the source code of my application:

```
   <Page x:Class="TestWpfApplication.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApplication"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="525"
  Title="Page1" Background="#FF7ACBBC" ShowsNavigationUI="False">

<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Heading" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="222.006,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="22"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,155,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="And rest of the content goes here" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14"/>

</Grid>
```

And

```
 <Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:Page1/>
</Grid>
```

At last App.xaml

```
 <Application x:Class="TestWpfApplication.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApplication"
         StartupUri="page1.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set SizeToContent Property of Window to SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
[SizeToContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent(v=vs.110).aspx)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Page1.Xaml.cs:**

```
public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
    }
```

For more Info, See [Window.SizeToContent Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you specified size parameters for rectangle and expect it to fit your page's size. Just remove all these parameters and it will stretch.

```
<Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5"/>
```